# Apply table function on multiple categorical variables with different categories

Tags: r, automation

I am transitioning from SAS to **R**. I need help with something I could do very easily do in SAS but I have no clue about this in **R**.

I have a dataframe with many categorical variables (all converted to factors), say X1 - X50. Each variable can have different categories.
For example,

```
         X1 can be Male, Female     
         x2 can be 1, 0       
         X3 can be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

I wanted to run a table command on all the 50 categorical variables together such that I get an output dataframe with three columns which looks like this:

```
Group Variable    Levels     Frequency  
   1     x1          Male         10     
   1     X1           Female       30    
   1     X2            1           5  
   1     X2            0           20    
   1     X2            Missing     15  
   1     X3            1           5  
   1     X3            2           5  
   1     X3            3           5  
   1     X3            4           10   
   1    X3            5           5  
   1    X3            Missing     5  
   2    
   2  
   2  
   2  
   2
```

I need univariate frequency distributions by group. So column Group identifies a subset of the original dataframe to compute frequencies by.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but in the right direction.

```
     mydata
      X1    X2
      Male   A
      Male   B
      Female C
      Female A
      Female C
as.data.frame(unlist(lapply(mydata, table))) #produces the following, 
          unlist(lapply(mydata, table))
X1.Female                             3
X1.Male                               2
X2.A                                  2
X2.B                                  1
X2.C                                  2
```